# Convert string (can be a decimal string or hex string) to integer C++

Tags: c++, std

Hello I want to convert a string into integer and that string can be either decimal or hex string in cpp.

For example: if input is "10" it should output 10, if input is "A" it should output corresponding decimal value which is 10.

I know for decimal string to integer we use std::stoul() and hex string to integer we use std::strtoul(), but is there anything can be done for both type of string, with/without checking the type of string?

Thanks

Comment: And what should it output for i.e `15`? Because that can be both hex and decimal.

Comment: The [`std::stoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) function can be used for almost any arbitrary base, just like [`std::strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul).

Comment: @Quimby You mean "e.g." (*exampli gratia* - "for example"), not "i.e" (*id est* - "that is").

Comment: You can put gas in a diesel car, but...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  std::stoul() throws exception with cause "std::invalid_argument" in case input is a hex string like "A"

Comment: Well if you didn't specify the base it default to base 10 (decimal). `A` is an invalid digit and will lead to an exception being thrown. As documented in the linked reference.

Comment: I actually wanted easiest way without checking string type. Okay, it seems no way other than to giving base value explicitly. Thanks.

Comment: there is no way to decide whether "10" is decimal or hexadecimal other than choosing one of the two

Comment: @user463035818 Or binary, or octal, or *any* base (larger than one) really.

Comment: @MartinBonner Thank you, I'm not native speaker and never knew for what they stand for so apparently I've been usem them wrongly for a long time.

Comment: @Quimby.  Your English is **much** better than my *your language* (unless it is German, in which case your English is merely "better").  My advice to non-native speakers is usually to use the English phrases - but I admit here it wouldn't have been as neat.

Answer (score 1):

In case of C++11 (or above) you could simply use std::stoi: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/

This way you could explicitly define how you want to interpret your string (i.e. decimal, hexadecimal, etc.)

Comment: For decimal string it's fine but for hex string it terminates throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'

Comment: @SelMez You have to tell the function what the base is.  It won't figure it out for you because something like `15` could be both decimal or hex.

Comment: How do you use it? For example `std::stoi("FF",0,16)` should give 255 as output.

Comment: So this implies I have no other option than to check what type of string it is ( base 10 or base 16) then apply stoi with base value. Actually I wanted it without doing checking

Comment: @SelMez For this solution yes.  There is a generic solution that you don't have to specify the base bu how do you have it handling something like `15`.  That is a valid decimal or hex integer so what do you expect to get?

Comment: How can you decide which format to use based on the value of the string? If you have the string "10", which format would you choose? It could be interpreted in both ways...

Comment: I missed that case. Thank you all for clearing my doubt. I got my answer